# Wordpress Site down for my own IP address

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-500

I just migrate my site to another hosting provider using wordpress Duplicator plugin. Before waiting for DNS propagate, i already change the host file so that I can run the installer file from Duplicator. When everything is done, I revert the host file to original, but then my site appear as white screen of death (other browsers) and 500 error (chrome). But it looks perfectly fine when I test it from other ip adress (mobile 4g, or home wifi), it only fail for my work wifi. Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

ps: I have checked my own IP address is not blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please clear your cookies, flush dns and restart your router. should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Open your wp-config.php and change line from `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. If you don't have this line in your `wp-config.php` then you should add it after database settings.

You will reload a page after the changes and will see more details of error

Read more about [Wordpress Debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: I have checked the error log after define wp_debug to true. It only got one error: PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0